# Página con Warning: "A non-numeric value encountered in...on line 462"

Tags: php

Hace poco hice un cambio de hosting de mi página, pero ahora me está saliendo un: "Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /home/u876692115/domains/erretres.com.co/public_html/wp-content/themes/kloe/framework/modules/title/title-functions.php on line 462" que antes no aparecía, qué podría hacer para arreglarlo?. Pongo el código a continuación de esa línea:

if(!function_exists('kloe_qodef_title_area_height')) {
    /**
     * Function that returns title height and padding to be applied in template
     **/

```
function kloe_qodef_title_area_height() {
    $id = kloe_qodef_get_page_id();
    $title_height_and_padding = array();
    $title_height          = kloe_qodef_get_title_area_height();
    $header_height_padding = kloe_qodef_get_title_content_padding();
    $title_vertical_alignment = 'header_bottom';
    $title_holder_height = '';
    $title_subtitle_holder_padding = '';

    //is responsive image is set for current page?
    if(($meta_temp = get_post_meta($id, "qodef_title_area_background_image_responsive_meta", true)) != "") {
        $is_img_responsive = $meta_temp;
    } else {
        //take value from theme options
        $is_img_responsive = kloe_qodef_options()->getOptionValue('title_area_background_image_responsive');
    }

    if(($meta_temp = get_post_meta($id, "qodef_title_area_vertial_alignment_meta", true)) !== '') {
        $title_vertical_alignment = $meta_temp;
    }else{
        $title_vertical_alignment = kloe_qodef_options()->getOptionValue('title_area_vertial_alignment');;
    }

    //we need to define title height only when aligning text bellog header and when image isn't responsive
    if($is_img_responsive !== 'yes' && $title_vertical_alignment == 'header_bottom') {
        $title_holder_height = 'height:'.$title_height.'px;';
    }
    //we need to add padding-top property only if we are aligning title text from bellow header
    if($title_vertical_alignment == 'header_bottom' && !empty($header_height_padding)) {
        if($is_img_responsive == 'yes') {
            $title_subtitle_holder_padding = 'padding-top: '.$header_height_padding.'px;';
        } else {
            $title_holder_height .= 'padding-top: '.$header_height_padding.'px;';
        }
    }

    //increase title height for the height of header transparent parts
    $title_height_and_padding['title_height'] = 'height:'.($title_height + $header_height_padding).'px;';
    $title_height_and_padding['title_holder_height'] = $title_holder_height;
    $title_height_and_padding['title_subtitle_holder_padding'] = $title_subtitle_holder_padding;


    return $title_height_and_padding;
}
```

}

adjunto imagen[image: warning]

Comment: Por favor, no pongas tu codigo como imagen sino como texto. y cual es el warning completo?

Comment: Hola, ya edité la pregunta con parte del código. El warning es el siguiente: Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /home/u876692115/domains/erretres.com.co/public_html/wp-content/themes/kloe/framework/modules/title/title-functions.php on line 462

Comment: Y debe ser que no viene un valor numerico. Debuguealo de alguna forma para ver que viene

Comment: No tienes por qué publicar la ruta completa de tu sitio web, es mejor poner algo así: `/MiHome/MiID/midominio.com/public_html/` A veces los hackers se sirven de esas rutas ya conocidas para hurgar en tu sistema, sabiendo ya que tienes ahí Wordpress y que tienes tal o cual tema o framework.

Comment: El error es claro, en la operación de suma uno de los operandos no es un número, en esta operacion `($title_height + $header_height_padding)`, una o mas de las variables no tiene un valor númerico. El valor de esas variables es asignado con la llamada a otras funciones, revisa que es lo que retornan esas funciones y si es lo que esperas.

Comment: Dado que el archivo parece ser propio de un tema o plugin, revisa si dicho tema o plugin está actualizado. A veces ciertos temas o plugin dan ese tipo de errores al pasar por ejemplo a PHP 7, donde se hace un control de tipos más estricto que en versiones anteriores de PHP.